# Gunicorn memory quota excedeed

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, heroku, gunicorn

I have a python application that needs to display a video stream in the browser. For displaying the stream I make a request to one another route(/video_feed). Here is the code:

```
@app.route("/video_feed")
def video_feed():
    # return the response generated along with the specific media
    # type (mime type)
    return Response(generate(),
                    mimetype="multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame")
```

```
def generate():
    # grab global references to the output frame and lock variables
    global outputFrame, lock

    # loop over frames from the output stream
    while True:
        # wait until the lock is acquired
        with lock:
            # check if the output frame is available, otherwise skip
            # the iteration of the loop
            if outputFrame is None:
                continue

            # encode the frame in JPEG format
            (flag, encodedImage) = cv2.imencode(".jpg", outputFrame)

            # ensure the frame was successfully encoded
            if not flag:
                continue

        # yield the output frame in the byte format
        yield (b'--frame\r\n' b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' +
               bytearray(encodedImage) + b'\r\n')
```

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Pi Video Surveillance</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Pi Video Surveillance</h1>
    <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
  </body>
</html>
```

```
@app.route('/stream')
def show_video_stream():
    return render_template("stream.html")
```

```
def prepare_video_stream():
    print("It might be streaing")
    global outputFrame, lock
    coordinates_file = "data/parking_spot_coordinates.yml"
    with open(coordinates_file, "r") as coordinates_data:
        coordinates = yaml.load(coordinates_data)
        stream_url = os.environ.get('RTSP_URL')
        video_stream = VideoStream(coordinates)
        # video_stream.stream_video()
        video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(stream_url)
        fps = video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
        print(fps)
        video_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 0)

        while video_capture.isOpened():
            frame = video_stream.get_frame(video_capture)
            # acquire the lock, set the output frame, and release the
            # lock
            with lock:
                outputFrame = frame.copy()
```

```
@app.before_first_request
def start_stream_processing_thread():
    # # start a thread that will perform motion detection
    t = threading.Thread(target=prepare_video_stream)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
```

Everything runs fine when ran locally with the built-in flask server, but I tried deploying the application to heroku with gunicorn as a server. Here is the Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

When checking heroku logs I get the following:
Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)

How can I avoid this?